# NP-completeness of chromatic sum in list coloring problem with capacity constraints

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, coloring, np-complete, decision-theory

I am trying to solve a problem that can be considered as minimizing the sum of colored numbers in a List Coloring Problem while satisfying some restricted constraints.

In the List Coloring Problem (LCP), one is given an undirected graph $G(V,E)$, each vertex $v \in V$ is given a list
of permissible colors $L(v) \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,k\}$, we want to find a coloring $c$ such that $c(v) \in L(v)$ for all $v \in V$ and $c(i) \neq c(j)$ for all $<i,j> \in E$. If such a coloring exists, we say that $G$ is $L$-colorable and that $c$ is an $L$-coloring of $G$.

In my problem: Given: 1) a graph $G(V,E)$; 2) an integer $k$, for tractability, we use a natural number from 1 to k (i.e., the total number of colors is $k$) to represent a color one by one. We assume that each color has a specific capacity, i.e., how many times it can be used at most in $G$, and each vertex must be assigned by an exact number. The objective is to minimize the sum of color numbers of $v \in V$ while satisfying no any two adjacent vertices are assigned same number and the color capacity is not violated.

I want to prove the above problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. 
The only possible reduction I can come up with seemingly is to reduce the $L$-colorable List Coloring Problem to my problem. It is well known $k$-colorable in graph coloring problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete and the List Coloring Problem is a generalization of graph coloring problem, can I say the $k$-coloring in List Coloring Problem is also $\mathcal{NP}$-complete? 
Moreover, I am not very sure whether a problem is still $\mathcal{NP}$-complete after adding capacity constraints.

I in advance appreciate if someone can give any useful suggestions!

Comment: I just reword, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge here is not that your problem has "added capacity constraints" -- that just gives you a *richer* language of instances, and you can just chose not to *use* that possibility when you generate instances of your problem as part of the reduction. But it **is** a challenge that your problem *doesn't have* the explicit color list constraints, because you need to find a way to handle input instances that do have nontrivial list constraints.

In order to reduce LCP to your problem, you must show how to take an LCP instance and -- in polynomial time -- produce an instance of your problem that has the same answer.

Suppose the LCP instance has $v$ vertices and $k$ colors. Without loss of generality I'll assume there's at least one edge, too, such that the vertices can't all have the same color.

Now, suppose we add $v$ new vertices that we will force to have color $1$, and $2v$ new vertices that we will force to have color $2$, and so forth up to $kv$ new vertices that will be forced to have color $k$. This "forcing" can happen by

- connecting each of the new vertices to every other new vertex that will get a different color, *and*
- giving color $n$ a capacity of $nv+v-1$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,k$.

Now the only way to satisfy the capacities is by giving each new vertex the desired color. We can then enforce the color lists by adding edges between each *old* vertex and new vertices of the colors that old vertex *must not have*.

This gives you an instance of *your* problem that is solvable iff the original LCP instance was.

Comment: @Wei: Well, solving your problem requires also solving the decision problem of whether a solution that meets the constraints exists at all, doesn't it?

Comment: I think so. I think a lot and try to prove that the sum of color numbers is minimized iff a k-colorable in LCP is solvable.

Comment: @Wei: Then you don't need to care about the fact that your problem _would_ also minimize something! Just ask, "does this instance of the problem have a solution with sum less than $k^2v^2$?"

Comment: But I am still confused how to make this convinced: the sum of color numbers is minimized iff a LCP is k-colorable? Thanks again!

Comment: @Wei: When you're reducing TO your problem _you're the one who decides what the particular instance of your problem you construct will look like_. Nobody says you have to use everything it can do! (It would be different if you're _solving_ your problem, but that's _not_ what you're doing here. When you're reducing TO the problem, you imagine that _someone else_ has constructed a machine for your problem, and you're then imagining what you can _do_ with that machine. You don't need to press all of the buttons if there are a few of the buttons that can do the thing you want!)

Comment: Or, if I can show an instance of my problem is k-colorable and the sum of color numbers is a constant about k iff the k-colorable in LCP is solvable.

Comment: @Wei: (deleted comment)

Comment: (Sorry, it is confusing that "solvable" has two different meanings here; one applies to problem _instances_ and the other to the general problem of finding a polynomial algorithm for the entire problem. I may be misunderstanding what you're saying).

Comment: @Wei: Correct: When you're reducing from LCP to your problem, you should assume that **someone else** has found a magical method to decide your problem. You're not concerned with how it works. All you're doing is show how to _exploit_ that magical solution to decide LCP too. This means that you need to give a procedure that can _handle all possible LCP instances_, but it doesn't need to be able to _produce all possible instances of your problem_.

Comment: In particular, you're allowed to ignore the fact that the magical solution tells you a minimal solution, if all you _need_ is that you can ask it about whether there is _any_ solution at all.

Comment: To sum up, what I need to do is to prove "Given graph G = (V,E); positive integer K; color number capacity (can be ignored during proof). "Is there a proper coloring assignment of graph G such that the sum of color numbers is less than a constant times K (cK)? "

Comment: The first step is to find a well known NP-complete (like LCP) and reduce it to my problem. Then, construct a instance (G' and K') with the property that the sum of color numbers is less than cK iff G is K-colorable. Next is to prove this property and vice versa! Finally, I can say my problem is also NP-complete, is that correct?